# Reducing latency before retrieving a local terminal when an SSH session has expired

Tags: networking, command-line, server, ssh, 22.04

When working on a remote server, I open an SSH connection in a  terminal `ssh remote_username@remote_host`.

For some reason, if I left this connection idle for too long, the terminal becomes unresponsive, e.g. whatever key I hit, absolutely nothing happens.

But after a certain amount of time, I'm given back the hand on the underlying local terminal and I can work again:

```sh
remote_user@remote_server:~$ # <--- whatever I type, nothing happens
# many minutes later, this is printed:
remote_user@remote_server:~$ client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe
local_user@local_machine:~ # and I'm given back the hand on my local terminal
```

This amount of time is quite long (many minutes).

Hence my question: is there a way to parametrize this delay on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS?

##### Versioning

- ssh: `OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022`
- bash: `GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Comment: Try setting the `ServerAliveInterval` environment variable to try and keep the session active ... e.g. `ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=120 user@localhost`

Answer (score 1):

You might need to set the option `ServerAliveInterval` ... From [`man ssh_config`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man5/ssh_config.5.html):

> **ServerAliveInterval**
>
> Sets a timeout interval in seconds after which if no data has been received from the server, ssh(1) will send a message through the
> encrypted channel to request a response from the server. The default
> is 0, indicating that these messages will not be sent to the server.

It takes a value as a number of seconds ... e.g. like so:

```
ServerAliveInterval 120
```

You can add that in a new line to `ssh` config either for your user in the file `~/.ssh/config`(*It's not there by default so you might need to create this file*) or globally in the file `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` ... Notice that you should add it under a `Host` keyword ... e.g. in the `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` there is a keyword `Host *` which means apply the below arguments to all remote hosts ... So you would add it to the existing arguments e.g. like so:

```
Host *
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
    HashKnownHosts yes
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
    ServerAliveInterval 120
```

**Alternatively**, as stated in [`man ssh`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/ssh.1.html):

> **-o option**
>
> Can be used to give options in the format used in the configuration
> file.

You can set that option directly in the command itself ... e.g. like so:

```bash
ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=120 user@host
```

Answer (score 0):

I see this sometimes with my home connection to a remote server. One workaround is to leave something running on the remote end which produces output, so traffic is constantly flowing, but not to much that it's a bandwidth hog. What I use is [Byobu](https://www.byobu.org/)

[image]

While running, Byobu has a clock on screen (along with other things like disk space, and other useful data) in the status bar. Having that on screen typically stops the connection timing out.